# __cyg_profile_func_enter and g++ 2.95.4

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, profiler

I want to get function's call stack of the programm with gcc option -finstrument-functions.

Typical code

```
void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
int depth = -1;

void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller)
{    }

void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func, void *caller)
{    }

int main()
{
printf("Hello world");
return 0
}
```

Compile it with gcc -finstrument-functions test.c

run ./a.out, and all ok.

But when I did it with g++ , I got undefined reference to __cyg_profile_func_enter function. I read that it happens because _cyg functions is part of C code and if I want to use them in C++ I should use extern "C", so there is final code.

```
extern "C"{
void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *, void *) __attribute__((no_instrument_function));
int depth = -1;

void __cyg_profile_func_enter (void *func,  void *caller)
{    }

void __cyg_profile_func_exit (void *func, void *caller)
{    }
}
int main()
{
printf("Hello world");
return 0
}
```

It compiles with  g++ -finstrument-functions test.c, then try to execute it but got Core dumped error message. I trace dump with gdb and there was Segmentation fault in __cyg_profile_func_enter().

GCC version is 2.95.4. I also tested it on 4.4.3 and all Ok. So are there any posibilities to walk around this problem using 2.95.4 gcc?

Comment: did you manage to make this work with C++, any solution at hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

gcc 2.95.4 is over ten years old. I've managed to dig one out ... and compile your stuff. It obviously does not recognize `__attribute__((no_instrument_function))` because the generated assembly code has:

```
__cyg_profile_func_enter:
.LFB1:
        pushl %ebp
.LCFI0:
        movl %esp,%ebp
.LCFI1:
        subl $8,%esp
.LCFI2:
        movl 4(%ebp),%eax
        addl $-8,%esp
        pushl %eax
        pushl $__cyg_profile_func_enter
.LCFI3:
        call __cyg_profile_func_enter
        movl 4(%ebp),%eax
        addl $16,%esp
        addl $-8,%esp
        pushl %eax
        pushl $__cyg_profile_func_enter
        call __cyg_profile_func_exit
        movl %ebp,%esp
        popl %ebp
        ret
```

So it recursively calls itself and that of course ends in a stack overflow.

If you really require both gcc 2.95.x (facing heaven, rolling eyes, wincing look on face, "why oh why ???") *and* `-finstrument-functions` then you'll have to make them "truly `extern`" - i.e. put them in a separate sourcefile which you compile *without* the option, and link that in later.

Comment: Was there even ever an official .4 release? This smells a bit like a 2.96 where all hope on any sane code is lost...

Comment: So the main problem of g++ 2.95.4( it's really old) is that there are no option for it like    no_instrument_function?

Comment: @John Square: I don't really see _that_ as a particular problem; for one, it seems to affect only the C++ compiler (`g++`), and can be worked around by compiling the hook code with the C one (`gcc`) and/or without the `-finstrument-functions` option. gcc/g++ 2.9x has other problems that I'd rather not deal with, re language standards/features ... it's _really_ old, ass you say.  
@PlasmaHH: I used 2.95.3 to compile the above, as I couldn't find a 2.95.4.

Answer (score 3):

Even with gcc 4.4.3, no_instrument_functions doesn't work correctly in all cases.  If a function is inlined, then the instrumentation calls are added to it even if it has the no_instrument_functions attribute set.  Even -finstrument-functions-exclude-file-list doesn't work.

The only way to get it to work reliably is to put your tracing code into another file and compile this file without -finstrument-functions.

Comment: Yes, I did so and it works. Put __cyg_profile_func_enter(exit) in another file make from it shared library. So if I want to use my code of fins-function I just recompile needed code with -finstrument-functions and link my library